# How to add SPAN class and Style to selected Text in CKEditor 5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have developed new Plugin 'Small Caps' in CKEditor5. Basically, it should add span class or style as `{'font-variant': 'small-caps'}`.
I am trying with different editor methods, however, I am not able to find anything which can fulfill my requirement.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this? Do I need to make custom command class? Which API would add span attribute with css class or styleset?

Answer (score 0):

We've created a plugin for this purpose:

https://github.com/HCESrl/ckeditor5-small-caps

I hope it helps!